# In Oracle 12.2c purge a queue don't update counters un gv$aq

Tags: oracle, queue

I have a problem en Oracle 12.2c, this code works fine in Oracle 10g:

I create a message queue:

```
begin
dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table(
 queue_table => 'QT_test',
 queue_payload_type => 'RAW',
 storage_clause => 'PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 99',
 sort_list => 'ENQ_TIME',
 comment => 'Test Queue Table',
 secure => FALSE);
 
 dbms_aqadm.create_queue(
 queue_name => 'Q_Test',
 queue_table => 'QT_test',
 queue_type => dbms_aqadm.NORMAL_QUEUE,
 max_retries => 3,
 retry_delay => 1);
end;
```

I enqueue message and view it without problem:

```
declare
 eq_msgid RAW(16);
 usermsg RAW(160);
 eq_opt   dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
 msg_prop dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
BEGIN
 msg_prop.priority := 1;
 eq_opt.visibility := dbms_aq.immediate;
 msg_prop.delay := dbms_aq.no_delay;
 msg_prop.expiration := 1;   
 dbms_aqadm.start_queue('Q_Test');
 dbms_aq.enqueue('Q_Test', eq_opt, msg_prop, usermsg, eq_msgid);
 COMMIT;
end;
/
SELECT * FROM GV$AQ GV, all_queues AQ WHERE OWNER = USER AND GV.QID = AQ.QID AND 
AQ.QUEUE_TABLE='QT_TEST';
SELECT * FROM AQ$QT_TEST;
```

I do a purge, but counters are not updated:

```
declare
 po dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
begin
 po.block := false;
 dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table(queue_table => 'QT_TEST',purge_condition => NULL,purge_options => po);
end;
/
SELECT * FROM GV$AQ GV, all_queues AQ WHERE OWNER = USER AND GV.QID = AQ.QID AND 
AQ.QUEUE_TABLE='QT_TEST';
SELECT * FROM AQ$QT_TEST;
```

I cannot show messages in QT, I cannot dequeue anything but the counters in GV$AQ show the count of the older messages.